# Setup of motor control with remote and limit switches

Tags: relay, dc-motor, automation

I have a need to setup a rig that will raise and lower at the press of a button. I have two 12v motors which run the two ends of a gantry (i am not worried about speed control - since I will add that) however I am struggling to understand how i will wire this setup.

essentially what I dont know

- how to connect the limit switches
- If i can reliably use a transmitter to send the "up" and "down" signal or if i should have a 777 timer in the mix also.
- how to make the motor change direction for up and down buttons - it doesnt need to reverse direction at the end stops, just needs to stop.

I have created a diagram which illustrates the issue?
[image]

Comment: Despite all your effort in making a diagram, this is still a 'please design a system for me' question. We do not offer complete designs here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I understand fully. I will edit the question with a proposed solution  - I think what I am asking is -- are these components sufficient?

Comment: yes those components are sufficient. Hint: use the limit swithches NC in series with the relay trigger signal.